# Why pthread_create does not work 100% of the times?

Tags: c, pthreads, gnu

I am recently learning about threads in C, and I have noticed something I consider weird.
Let's take the next code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void    *sub_routine(void *p)
{
    p = NULL;
    printf("This is a sub_routine\n");
    return (NULL);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    void        *p;
    pthread_t   thread;

    if (argc < 1)
        return (0);
    p = argv[1];
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, sub_routine, NULL);
    sub_routine(p);
    return (0);
}
```

I use this command line to compile my program:

```bash
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pthread pthreads.c
```

The expected result is to print `This is a sub_routine` two times. Well that happens but not 100% of the times. Is there any particular reason for that?

Comment: You have to put a `pthread_join`, otherwise `main` can returns while the thread is still running.

Answer (score 2):

When `main` returns, it exits the program even if other threads are running. Therefore, it’s possible for the thread you spawned to not get to the `printf` before the main thread returns, in which case the program ends before you’ll see both messages.

One way to address this is to add a call to `pthread_join` at the end of `main` to tell the program to wait for the thread you created to finish running before main returns. That will ensure you always see two printouts.

Comment: So, what I understand from you is that the exiting of the main process does not guarantee the exiting of other threads under the same process. Is that right?

Comment: I may be mistaken about this, but if the main thread finishes running by returning from `main`, then it forcibly stops all other threads and doesn’t wait for them to finish first.

Comment: It sort of depends. But if you write multi-threaded programs, don't depend on what compilers may or may not come up with. Just nicely deal with any thread you spawn.

Comment: @templatetypedef it's probably more correct to say that the language runtime is entirely unaware of the other threads and makes no effort stop or tidy them up.  This is left to the operating system in implementations of C for general purpose operating systems.

There is much potential for undefined behaviour if resources created by the main thread are cleaned up before the call to `exit()` or `main()` returning are used by threads that are still running.  This is a huge trap in C++ and is possible to achieve in C too.

Comment: Also, for the sake of completion, calling `pthread_join()` on all threads spawned is a recipe for a deadlock if threads are blocked on something - for instance I/O - or a live-lock if they never exit.  Also, most POSIX threads implementations provide no way of killing threads - they have to die by returning from their thread-function.

Answer (score 1):

Add pthread_join(thread, NULL) at the end (just before return) of the main thread to join the thread "sub_routine"

The modified version of your code works properly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void    *sub_routine(void *p)
{
    p = NULL;
    printf("This is a sub_routine\n");
    return (NULL);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    void        *p;
    pthread_t   thread;

    if (argc < 1)
        return (0);
    p = argv[1];
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, sub_routine, NULL);
    sub_routine(p);
    pthread_join(thread, NULL);
    return (0);
}
```